# I have a mysql query I've been working on and can't make it work

Tags: mysql, nested

The introID is the ID of the member that introduce certain member into the program.
Original extracted data:

```
ID  | parentID | introID | name
45       15        12      Rasika Bedekar   
41       14        10      Arjun Rampal 
29       10        8       Raju Aswani  
32       11        8       Sheetal Bhadra   
47       16        8       Luna Verma   
50       17        8       Vinod Gala   
68       23        8       Vibha Palte  
53       18        5       Rashid Khan  
54       18        5       Irfan Pathan
1        0         0       Manish Shah  
2        1         0       Nirmal Malik
```

building the first report, we get all members in each level with this query:

```
`select a.ID, a.parentID, a.name,(select count(*) from members where introID = a.ID) as     intro,
count(distinct b.ID) as level1,
count(distinct c.ID) as level2,
count(distinct d.ID) as level3,
count(distinct e.ID) as level4,
count(distinct f.ID) as level5,
count(distinct g.ID) as level6,
count(distinct h.ID) as level7,
count(distinct i.ID) as level8,
count(distinct j.ID) as level9,
count(distinct k.ID) as level10
from members a
left join members b on b.parentID = a.ID
left join members c on c.parentID = b.ID
left join members d on d.parentID = c.ID
left join members e on e.parentID = d.ID
left join members f on f.parentID = e.ID
left join members g on g.parentID = f.ID
left join members h on h.parentID = g.ID
left join members i on i.parentID = h.ID
left join members j on j.parentID = i.ID
left join members k on k.parentID = j.ID
left join members l on l.parentID = k.ID
where a.ID IN (select ID from members) group by ID`
```

And the results are this:

```
ID | parentID | name | totals_intro | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
1       0       name1        0           3       9        27       81
2       1       name2        0           3       9        27       36
3       1       name3        0           3       9        27       0
4       1       name4        0           3       9        27       0
5       2       name5        2           3       9        27       0
```

The problem, How to get totals_intro per level? level1_intro, level2_itro and so on...
The results from each level are the universe of ID's to look for on the next level introID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an answer and following the Adjacency list model someone else figure how to build the query:

```
select a.ID, a.name, (select count(*) from members where introID = a.ID) as Total_introduced, 
count(distinct b.ID) as level1,
count(distinct c.ID) as level2,
count(distinct d.ID) as level3,
count(distinct e.ID) as level4,
count(distinct f.ID) as level5, 
count(distinct g.ID) as level6,
count(distinct h.ID) as level7,
count(distinct i.ID) as level8,
count(distinct j.ID) as level9,
count(distinct k.ID) as level10,
COUNT(distinct IF(b.introID = a.ID, b.ID, NULL)) AS I1,
COUNT(distinct IF(c.introID = a.ID, c.ID, NULL)) AS I2,
COUNT(distinct IF(d.introID = a.ID, d.ID, NULL)) AS I3,
COUNT(distinct IF(e.introID = a.ID, e.ID, NULL)) AS I4,
COUNT(distinct IF(f.introID = a.ID, f.ID, NULL)) AS I5,
COUNT(distinct IF(g.introID = a.ID, g.ID, NULL)) AS I6,
COUNT(distinct IF(h.introID = a.ID, h.ID, NULL)) AS I7,
COUNT(distinct IF(i.introID = a.ID, i.ID, NULL)) AS I8,
COUNT(distinct IF(j.introID = a.ID, j.ID, NULL)) AS I9,
COUNT(distinct IF(k.introID = a.ID, k.ID, NULL)) AS I10
from members a
left join members b on b.parentID = a.ID 
left join members c on c.parentID = b.ID 
left join members d on d.parentID = c.ID 
left join members e on e.parentID = d.ID 
left join members f on f.parentID = e.ID
left join members g on g.parentID = f.ID
left join members h on h.parentID = g.ID
left join members i on i.parentID = h.ID
left join members j on j.parentID = i.ID
left join members k on k.parentID = j.ID
left join members l on l.parentID = k.ID
where a.ID IN (select ID from members) group by ID
```